# How to format results of an multidimentional array to display as a table in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I am trying to display results of mutlidimentional array as a table so it is easier readable by the user potentially using this script.

I am getting the result displayed by looping through each object in the array. However, it is all crammed together and not very readable for the user to make a decision.

```
Write-Host "Avalible Resource Pools at Site A" -ForegroundColor White

$ResourceA = Get-ResourcePool -Server $vmhostA |
             Sort-Object -Property name |
             Select-Object -Property name, CpuLimitMHz, MemReservationGB, MemLimitGB 

$menu = @{}

$selmenu = New-Object 'object[,]' 0,0
for ($i=1; $i -le $ResourceA.Count; $i++) {
    $selmenu += ,@($i, $ResourceA[$i-1].name, $ResourceA[$i-1].CpuLimitMHz, $ResourceA[$i-1].MemReservationGB, $ResourceA[$i-1].MemLimitGB)
    $menu.Add($i, ($ResourceA[$i-1].name))
}

foreach ($item in $selmenu) {
    Write-Host($item)
}

[int]$ans = Read-Host 'Enter selection'
$selection = $menu.Item($ans);
$selection
```

So currently the table is displayed as

```
1 Cloud -1 0 -1
2 Cloud 16568 31.25 31.25
3 CS -1 125 125
4 Cust Sols 22000 19.53125 19.53125
5 Devop -1 0 -1
6 Devop -1 500 -1
7 Tus' lab 35000 0 68.359375
8 IT -1 0 -1
9 IT -1 0 -1
10 IT -1 0 -1
11 PS-DMS -1 62.5 62.5
12 PS-Unbu 20000 4 29.296875
13 QA -1 116.2109375 -1
14 QA -1 0 -1
15 Resources 43248 750.6875 750.6875
16 Resources 44975 750.974609375 750.974609375
17 Resources 36378 246.8544921875 246.8544921875
18 Resources -1 0 -1
```

What I would like it to be displayed like below or similar with the headers

```
ID    Name       CPULimitMHz     MemReservationGB        MemoryLimitGB
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    Cloud        -1               0                      -1
2    Cloud        16568            31.25                  31.25
3    CS           -1               125                    125
4    Cust Sols    22000            19.53125               19.53125
5    Develop      -1               0                      -1
6    Develop      -1               500                    -1
7    Tus' lab     35000            0                       68.359375
8    IT           -1               0                       -1
9    IT           -1               0                       -1
10   IT           -1               0                       -1
11   PS-DMS       -1               62.5                    62.5
12   PS-Unbu      20000            4                       29.296875
13   QA           -1               116.2109375             -1
14   QA           -1               0                       -1
15   Resources    43248            750.6875                750.6875
16   Resources    44975            750.974609375           750.974609375
17   Resources    36378            246.8544921875          246.8544921875
18   Resources    -1               0                       -1
```

Any explanation would also be handy so I can replicate this to use for other parts of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a list of objects in tabular form: just pipe it into `Format-Table`.

```
$ResourceA | Format-Table
```

If you need an additional index column you can add that like this:

```
$global:id = 0
$ResourceA | Format-Table @{n='ID';e={$global:id;$global:id++}},*
```

However, a more user-friendly approach would probably be something like

```
$selection = $ResourceA | Out-GridView -PassThru
```

which will display a simple graphical selection dialog with filtering/sorting capabilities that will return the selected rows when closed. The returned rows are then stored in the variable `$selection`.

Comment: So $ResourceA is already formated but it doesn't give index comlum which is used then to give the selection. Thank you for this I think I can use the second option to give index to the table. However I also like the third option but I don't think this will get used in my script.
Thanks